# Absence changes in XSL doesn't run properly

Tags: xslt

Got the following error:

> Arithmetic operator is not defined for arguments of types
>   (xs:dateTime, xs:string)

Can anyone help me with this?  I am trying to do absence changes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:this="urn:this"
        xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
        xmlns:tv="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.TypedValue" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
        xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" exclude-result-prefixes="xs is tv wd bsvc"
        version="2.0">

        <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'" />

        <xsl:output method="text" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="StdHoursMultiplier" select="26" />

            <xsl:if
                test="wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_Data/wd:Terminated = '0' and not(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Status_Data/wd:On_Leave = '1') and not(exists(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Contingent_Worker_ID']))">

                <xsl:if
                    test="wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Job_Data/wd:Payee_Employment_Data/wd:Position_Data/wd:Job_Exempt != '0'">

                    <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(5,' ','TW')" />

                    <!-- employee id -->
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="this:right-padding(11,' ',substring(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Employee_ID']/text(),3,6))" />

                    <!-- earning code -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(6,' ','RGL')" />

                    <!-- amount type -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(4,' ','H')" />

                    <!-- text -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(7,' ','1')" />

                    <!-- amount -->
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="this:left-padding(8,' ',format-number((number(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Job_Data/wd:Payee_Employment_Data/wd:Position_Data/wd:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours)*52) div $StdHoursMultiplier,'####.00') )" />

                    <!-- line feed -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />

                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:for-each
                select="//wd:Payee_Earnings_and_Deductions_Summary_Data/wd:Payee_One_Time_Payments_Summary_Data/wd:Payee_One_Time_Payment_Summary_Data/wd:Payee_One_Time_Payment_Data">

                <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(5,' ','SP')" />

                <!-- employee id -->
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="this:right-padding(11,' ',substring(/wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Employee_ID']/text(),3,6))" />

                <!-- earning code -->
                <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(6,' ',../wd:External_Payroll_Code)" />

                <!-- amount type -->
                <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(4,' ','D')" />

                <!-- text -->
                <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(7,' ','1')" />

                <!-- amount -->
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="this:left-padding(10,' ',format-number(sum(wd:Amount/wd:Value),'####.00'))" />

                <!-- line feed -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:if
                test="wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_Data/wd:Terminated = '0' and (wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Status_Data/wd:On_Leave = '1') and not(exists(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Contingent_Worker_ID']))">

                <xsl:if
                    test="wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Job_Data/wd:Payee_Employment_Data/wd:Position_Data/wd:Job_Exempt != '0'"
                    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when
                            test="wd:Payee//wd:Payee_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Status_Data/wd:Paid_Time_off_Accrual_Effect = '1'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(5,' ','TW')" />

                            <!-- employee id -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:right-padding(11,' ',substring(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Employee_ID']/text(),3,6))" />

                            <!-- earning code -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(6,' ','RGL')" />

                            <!-- amount type -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(4,' ','H')" />

                            <!-- text -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(7,' ','1')" />

                            <!-- amount -->
                            <xsl:variable name="LeaveHours"
                                select="xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Estimated_Leave_End_Date) - xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Start_Date)cast as xs:string" />

                            <!-- amount -->


                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:left-padding(8,' ', '80')" />

                            <!-- line feed -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(5,' ','TW')" />

                            <!-- employee id -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:right-padding(11,' ',substring(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Employee_ID']/text(),3,6))" />

                            <!-- earning code -->


                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(6,' ','SDP')" />


                            <!-- amount type -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(4,' ','H')" />

                            <!-- text -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(7,' ','1')" />
                            <!-- amount -->


                            <!-- amount -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:left-padding(8,' ',format-number(number(substring-before(substring-after($LeaveHours,'P'),'D')),'####.00'))" />

                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when
                            test="not(wd:Payee//wd:Payee_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Status_Data/wd:Paid_Time_off_Accrual_Effect = '1')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(5,' ','TW')" />

                            <!-- employee id -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:right-padding(11,' ',substring(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Employee_ID']/text(),3,6))" />

                            <!-- earning code -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(6,' ','RGL')" />

                            <!-- amount type -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(4,' ','H')" />

                            <!-- text -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(7,' ','1')" />

                            <!-- amount -->

                            <!-- amount -->
                            <!-- amount -->
                            <xsl:variable name="LeaveHours"
                                select="xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Estimated_Leave_End_Date) - xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Start_Date) cast as xs:string" />


                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:left-padding(8,' ',format-number(number(substring-before(substring-after($LeaveHours,'P'),'D')),'####.00' ))" />


                            <!-- line feed -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(5,' ','TW')" />

                            <!-- employee id -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:right-padding(11,' ',substring(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Employee_ID']/text(),3,6))" />

                            <!-- earning code -->


                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(6,' ','SDP')" />


                            <!-- amount type -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(4,' ','H')" />

                            <!-- text -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(7,' ','1')" />
                            <!-- amount -->
                            <!-- amount -->

                            <xsl:value-of select="this:left-padding(8,' ','0')" />

                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(5,' ','TW')" />

                            <!-- employee id -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:right-padding(11,' ',substring(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Employee_ID']/text(),3,6))" />

                            <!-- earning code -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(6,' ','SDP')" />

                            <!-- amount type -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(4,' ','H')" />

                            <!-- text -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="this:right-padding(7,' ','1')" />

                            <!-- amount -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="this:left-padding(8,' ',format-number((number(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Job_Data/wd:Payee_Employment_Data/wd:Position_Data/wd:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours)*52) div $StdHoursMultiplier,'####.00') )" />

                        </xsl:otherwise>

                    </xsl:choose>


                </xsl:if>
                <!-- line feed -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:function name="this:right-padding">
            <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" />
            <xsl:param name="padChar" as="xs:string" />
            <xsl:param name="stringToPad" />

            <xsl:sequence
                select="substring(string-join(($stringToPad, for $i in (1 to $length) return $padChar),''),1,$length)" />

        </xsl:function>


        <xsl:function name="this:left-padding" as="xs:string">
            <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" />
            <xsl:param name="padChar" as="xs:string" />
            <xsl:param name="stringToPad" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($stringToPad) &gt; $length">
                    <xsl:sequence
                        select="substring($stringToPad, string-length($stringToPad) - $length + 1, $length)" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:sequence
                        select="substring(string-join((for $i in (1 to $length - string-length($stringToPad)) return $padChar, $stringToPad),''),1,$length)" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:function>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to a minimum to allow us to reproduce the error. And tell us exactly which line gives the error? Is that `xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Estimated_Leave_End_Date) - xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Start_Date) cast as xs:string`? Try to remove the `cast as xs:string` perhaps.

Comment: _It is very urgent_ this is not an emergency support site. Be patient and perhaps you'll get an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The code `<xsl:variable name="LeaveHours"
                                select="xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Estimated_Leave_End_Date) - xs:dateTime(wd:Payee/wd:Payee_Status_data/wd:leave_Status_Data/wd:Leave_Start_Date)cast as xs:string" />`
 should cause that error. Simply remove the trailing `cast as xs:string`, that way you can substract the two `xs:dateTime` values using the minus operator `-` just fine and get a duration value that you can process further as needed.